# C++ preprocessor directives like __TIME__ sometimes don't change/aren't updated

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c-preprocessor, fopen

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Express, and I have this logging code:

```
fprintf(fp,"%s %s %s %s %d %s\n", pType, __DATE__, __TIME__, pFileName, lineNo, pMsg.c_str());
fflush(fp);
```

Sometimes, if I don't delete the log and just keep appending to it, the `__TIME__` macro just keeps printing the old time, rather than the current time.

I'm using the following code to open the file

```
if(pfileName != NULL)
{
    fp = fopen(pfileName, "a+");
    if(fp != NULL)
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
}
```

Comment: Are you *recompiling* the code each time?

Comment: no .. doing build not rebuild

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is you're not doing a rebuild.

By default, Visual Studio only builds/compiles the source files that have *changed* (been modified) since the last time you have compiled your project. This is intended to save time, and it's a very useful feature. If you want to ensure that source files are recompiled, regardless of whether or not they've been changed since the last build, you have to instruct VS to *rebuild* your code (or go through the song and dance of doing a clean, and then a build on your project).

The reason why that matters is that the [`__TIME__` preprocessor macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) is expanded *during preprocessing* (which happens right before compilation, at least for our purposes here) with the current time. It got expanded the *first* time you compiled the code, and never gets changed unless you modify the source file or recompile (rebuild) it.

This is probably not what you're looking for in a logging function. Instead of the *compilation* time, you want to print the current *system* time. You can use the [`time` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33.aspx) to obtain that—to use it, make sure that you include `<time.h>` at the top of your source file. Or alternatively, if you're already including `<windows.h>`, you can call the [`GetSystemTime` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390.aspx) to fill a [`SYSTEMTIME` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950.aspx) that gives you the current time *and* date.

Comment: tl;dr: `__TIME__` is compile-time, `time()` is run-time. And you want run-time.

Answer (score 2):

`__TIME__` is

> The most recent compilation time of the current source file. The time is a string literal of the form hh:mm:ss.

This definition is from [Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

To get the current time you could use [time()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) or other similar function.